# Using NSXMLParser to get the First <created_at> entry to display the date of a Tweet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have my nsxmlparser that parsers the xml from twitter correctly, but i am having problems trying to get the date the tweet was posted.

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"created_at"])
    {
        currentTweet.dateEnteredRss = currentNodeContent;
    }
```

This picks up the date the account was created but not the tweet date

Has anyone else encountered this problem and has a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is dateEnteredRss an NSDate type? If so, you might want to use an NSDateFormatter to convert the string that your xml is reading into a date format.